# Syntax or convention used to describe Linux commands

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, zsh, man

If you apply `git clone --help` in the command line, your result will include something like the following:

```
git clone [--template=<template_directory>]
             [-l] [-s] [--no-hardlinks] [-q] [-n] [--bare] [--mirror]
             [-o <name>] [-b <name>] [-u <upload-pack>] [--reference <repository>]
             [--dissociate] [--separate-git-dir <git dir>]
             [--depth <depth>] [--[no-]single-branch] [--no-tags]
             [--recurse-submodules[=<pathspec>]] [--[no-]shallow-submodules]
             [--jobs <n>] [--] <repository> [<directory>]
```

Please anyone explain the meaning of the equal sign used in some options like `--template`.

I made an extensive search in Google and found [this](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-read-command-syntax-2618082) and [this](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/flashsystem-v7000u/1.5.2?topic=commands-command-syntax-conventions), but none of them explain what I want.

Please note that this question is not about Git, but about the syntax or convention used to describe linux commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `--template=<template_directory>` the character `=` is *literal*. Whatever you substitute for `<template_directory>` shall be appended to `--template=` and together they shall form one argument passed to `git` in the array of arguments. `=` is not special to the shell, it may be escaped or quoted in a shell. The argument may be quoted as a whole.

For comparison, in `--depth <depth>` there's a space character. You may perceive the space literally like `=` (i.e. say to yourself: I need `=` after `--template` but I need a space after `--depth`, it's just a different character, no big deal), but technically the mechanism is different. `git` expects the shell to split `--depth <depth>` to two arguments because of this space. It doesn't matter if you use one or more spaces (or tabs) when typing in a shell. What matters is the option `--depth` and whatever you substitute for `<depth>` shall be two arguments passed to `git` in the array of arguments. Therefore the space(s) must not be escaped nor quoted in a shell.

When there is no shell (i.e. when you craft an explicit *array* of arguments for `execve(2)` or similar), you should pass `--template=<template_directory>` as one argument, but `--depth`+`<depth>` as two.

Why `git` uses different conventions for different options is another matter. There may or may not be some rationale for the discrepancy in this specific case (i.e. in `git`).

In general a utility may interpret its arguments in its own way. Even if it follows one convention for `--foo`, it is by no technical means obliged to stick to the same convention with `--bar`.

Comment: the `getopt_long()` API from GNU accepts both `--foo arg` and `--foo=arg` for options that take a required argument, but only `--bar=arg` for options that take an optional argument (and `--bar whatever` means `--bar` without argument and `whatever` being an unrelated argument). (I don't know if `git` uses `getopt_long()` or if it parses its option in a similar way)

Answer (score 0):

There is very little formal syntax for that type of usage message, but there are a lot of conventions typically followed.

The angle bracket syntax `<thing>` typically indicates some parameter you supply.  The `--template=` part is pretty much literal, typed as is. The `=` is not special to the "syntax" of the description, it is part of the syntax of the actual command.

If you want more information, you should check the man page.  `man git-clone` says:

> --template=<template_directory>
>
> > Specify the directory from which templates will be used; (See the "TEMPLATE DIRECTORY" section of git-init(1).)

If the syntax of the usage message isn't clear, the man page should be.

Comment: That means some options and their arguments are separated by equal sign while some other options and their arguments are separated by a space character. This even happens in one single command. Why this inconsistent behaviour in Linux commands?

Comment: You'd have to ask the author that question.  Frequently when I see that, the command actually accepts it either way.